# Is it better to have a null record to avoid left joins?

Tags: sql, t-sql

For simplify my case, I use this example. I have a table Computers and a table States. Computers has the information of the computers and States the state of the computer (wating reapir, repaired... etc).

The tables are:

Computers(IDComputer, IDState, ...) 
Status(IDState, StateCode)

In some cases the computer can has no state, so IDState in the Computers table can be null. This makes me that in some situations I have to make a left join query.

But I am thinking in the possibility of to have a null state in the States table. this improve performance for not to use left joins or the performance is the same?

Comment: It seems to be a valid "state" to have no state. So i would make an `unassigned`-state for this.

Comment: What's wrong with a `LEFT JOIN`? Why do you feel they should be avoided?

Comment: There is nothing bad in LEFT JOINs, but agree with @TimSchmelter no state is valid state so application should take care of assigning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think performance would be badly affected by a left outer join on Status: not unless you have many,many possible states. If you've got only a few an outer join will not have a large cost. 
Having said that, you should actually find evidence before trying to optimise: look at sample queries and their query plans. Do the query plans look sensible? You may end up with a table scan on the Status table, but is there are only 10's of rows in it and not 100's then you're probably OK.

And having said *that*, I would personally add an 'Unknown' state (or whatever is reasonable to call it). It makes all coding easier - no remembering that you have to use outer joins, it makes queries easier to read as well.